# Delphi 10 Seattle Update1 how can I stop service from host app

Tags: android, delphi, service, delphi-10-seattle

I use Delphi 10 Seattle update1 and I have an android service what I start from host app but I do not know how can I stop the service from the host application. Could anyone tell me, please?

Comment: How are you starting it in the first place?

Comment: I started it with the next command : FLocationServiceConn := TLocalServiceConnection.creatd; FLocationServiceConn.StartService('LocationService') ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting the service using the 
`TLocalServiceConnection.StartService()` method.  Embarcadero does not provide a corresponding `TLocalServiceConnection.StopService()` method, so you will have to call Android's [`Context.stopService()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) method directly.

Here is the source code for `TLocalServiceConnection.startService()` from `$(BDS)\source\rtl\android\System.Android.Service.pas`:

```
class procedure TLocalServiceConnection.StartService(const AServiceName: string);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
  LService: string;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
  LService := AServiceName;
  if not LService.StartsWith('com.embarcadero.services.') then
    LService := 'com.embarcadero.services.' + LService;
  LIntent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName(), TAndroidHelper.StringToJString(LService));
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startService(LIntent);
end;
```

You can replace `TAndroidHelper.Activity.startService()` with `TAndroidHelper.Activity.stopService()`:

```
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
begin
  LIntent := TJIntent.Create;
  LIntent.setClassName(TAndroidHelper.Context.getPackageName(), TAndroidHelper.StringToJString('com.embarcadero.services.LocationService'));
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.stopService(LIntent);
end;
```

Comment: My host app crashes after the calling stopService, as you wrote, but service well stopes. Compiling in Berlin 10.1.

Comment: Better is use TAndroidHelper.Context with startService or stopService (may be used in service)

Comment: FYI [RSP-16531 for Android service: add StopService, isServiceStarted](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16531)

Comment: @PaxBeach: what kind of crash exactly?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau how can I understand it?

Comment: @PaxBeach: I was simply pointing out that a feature request has already been made to Embarcadero to add support for `stopService()` in FMX so the code in my answer above would not be needed anymore.

Comment: If anyone's interested. I used the code suggested by Remi to stop my service which was started with the startservice command - in 10.1 (Berlin). The OnDestroy event handler of the TAndroidService was called after that, but that was then followed by a Segmentation Fault (11) in a place not in my code.

Comment: Further to this. The SF(11) was in usleep. It's probably good practice to stop any loops you have in your service before it closes - you know, the loops you made because you couldn't use TTimer in a service.